# WebApi authorization with JWT always return 401

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, jwt, authorize

I'm trying to implement WebApi authorization with JWT token. But whatever I try to do - it's always return `401`. Here is how it look like.

### WebApiConfig.cs

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

### Startup.cs

```
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

        }

        private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var issuer = "http://localhost:59640/";
            var audience = "099153c2625149bc8ecb3e85e03f0022";
            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64.Decode("IxrAjDoa2FqElO7IhrSrUJELhUckePEPVpaePlS_Xaw");

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                    }
                });
        }
```

### NuGet packages installed

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.ru" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.ru" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.ru" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.1.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.1.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.3.308261200" targetFramework="net461" />
```

### Headers in 401 answer

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →90
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Wed, 26 Jul 2017 05:20:21 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate →Bearer
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGV2XGFncm9tYXNoXFRlc3RcYXBpXHRlc3Q=?=
```

### Request headers

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFuZHJleS5zaGVka29AZ21haWwuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiYW5kcmV5LnNoZWRrb0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJyb2xlIjoiQWRtaW4iLCJpc3MiOiJhZ3JvbWFzaC5hcGkiLCJhdWQiOiIwOTkxNTNjMjYyNTE0OWJjOGVjYjNlODVlMDNmMDAyMiIsImV4cCI6MTUwMTA0ODA2NiwibmJmIjoxNTAxMDQ2MjY2fQ.XkHk38NWcVXokzettDrngoL9BFiP_gEzswQaEYxVK10
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
```

What is interesting - when I changed `Authorize` attribute to custom authorize attribute it's even wasn't hit breakpoint inside custom authorize attribute but return `401`. I spent few days already trying to solve this problem. Could you tell me please - what I'm doing wrong?
**P.S.** JWT token I did validate on jwt.io and look like it's ok.

Comment: can you add the headers from the request also?

Comment: @hotzu I just updated my question.

Comment: I checked your jwt token. If I'm right, your 'exp' time is already passed, so probably your token is invalidated by time. Did you checked it?

Comment: @hotzu, that's just example, but let me check this again.

Comment: @hotzu, look like you are right.

Comment: should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @hotzu, yes, please.

Comment: @andrey.shedko did you determine what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your jwt token. If I'm right, your 'exp' time is already passed, so probably your token is invalidated by time.

Comment: Sorry, but seemed like the problem somewhere else.